# How to notify on Galaxy Gear

Tags: java, android, notifications, galaxy, sony-smartwatch

I am writing an app for Galaxy Gear for some research.
I need to "catch" the notifications coming up from the phone and throw my own notifications on the Gear.

**Well, the point is: How do I notify on Gear itself?**

Following code worked on Galaxy S4, but doesn't throw a notification on Galaxy Gear...

I created a SERVICE with doing the code below in methods "onCreated()" and "onStartCommand()":
MyNotificationSvc.java

```
private void doJob() throws InterruptedException{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
    stopSelf();
}
```

I started "MyNotificationSvc", when the Button "StartSvc" was clicked.
On click, the app is "minimized" and after 10 seconds a notification should be come up.
NOTICE: Not from Smartphone! Notification should come up from Galaxy Gear itself.

The onClick-method for "StartSvc"-Button is:

```
    public void startSvc(View v){
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startService(new Intent(this, MyNotificationSvc.class));
}
```

And I added this line in AppManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyNotificationSvc"></service>
```

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You should Start Gear Manager app on your phone Go to Notifications and select from the list of apps the app that you want to send notifications to the gear.